# TinyMCE change value inputs

Tags: reactjs, tinymce

Hello i use tinymce to add html pages that need to be rendered in a template engine in rust when edited with tinymce, on a form i need a place holder for the template to substitute with the data,

the problem is that the place holder is like this

> {{ data }}

so i need to do like this

```
<input type="hidden" value={{ data }} id="data" name="data" />
```

but when i paste it to tinyMCE source in the editor the place holder get changed with

> value="{{"

how can i disable the value changing and leave the place holder?

i've already tried with a template and the placeholder in the input works